# Accessing audio samples on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio

I want to code up a audio fx program that would process the samples coming in through the mic input and play them through the audio output in near realtime. But I cannot seem to figure out how to get accesses to the individual audio samples as they come in. Can. Anybody point me in the right  direction and possibly some sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The audio-processing framework in iOS is called Core Audio. See the [Core Audio Overview](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html). For sample code see the [iOS Reference Library sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code). You can filter for audio using the searchbox

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be looking at the Audio Queue services (most/all of the function names begin with "AudioQueue").